# What is the term used for the act of casting a void pointer into a pointer to a type?

Tags: c++, c, programming-languages, nomenclature

What is the term used (say, by programming language theorists) for the act of casting a void pointer into a pointer to a type? Is it "upcasting"? "type infusion"? "typing"?

**Notes:**

- It is obviously a cast, and obviously a reinterpreting cast - but I'm looking for a more specific term, expressive of the transition from an untyped to a typed pointee.
- Please do not argue about whether it's a good idea to avoid this or not, that is really not the question.

Comment: It's a cast IMO. A pointer to void is a type, and a pointer to int, ie, is another type. So with void `*p=NULL; int *i = (int *)p;` I'm casting a void pointer to an int pointer.

Comment: C or C++? In C I would say the term is "unnecessary".

Comment: Nothing? You have to spell it out.

Comment: It's called casting.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Why would it be necessary in C++?

Comment: @WeatherVane: The phrasing of your question, at least to me implied that your statement held true for C but not for C++. Otherwise why ask "C or C++?"? Never mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to make up a new term, you could call it *type unerasure*.

Comment: That term is assuming the target type was once erased, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: @einpoklum: How so? Is there some way of creating objects of type `void` that I'm not aware of? If you're referring to interpretation of serialised data then I submit that the original data still had a type, even if only by the as-if rule :)

Comment: Well, while it's probably/certainly the case something was cast into a void*, it's very possible the reinterpreting cast will not be back to that type. I might have had a char*, played with the bits, and ended up with a valid float at the target address. But, you know, I guess it's a good enough term on second thought. Accepted.

Comment: @einpoklum: _Type invention_ perhaps ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say such is ***brute force casting*** (or just *casting* like the c nitpickers will call it) like it's represented in c++ with the proper `reinterpret_cast<>`, hence ***reinterpret casting***.

Comment: this is the correct answer. why the downvotes? it's a reinterpret cast, pure and simple.

Comment: @RichardHodges It was foreseeable that answer will get downvotes. People don't like to hear what's the truth.

Comment: ain't that the truth :)

Comment: Not really a pun; rather it's a play on words. Nicely done, but I've reported it because it's the truth. ;)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: But `(int) my_crazy_typed_value` is also brute-force casting. I want to capture the point of there not being an implied type before the cast, and there being one afterwards.

Comment: @einpoklum That's still a _brute force_ reinterpret cast. I don't get what you're really after with your question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It is indeed a "brute force cast". It is also a "cast". It is also a "computational action". I want the specific term, that's all.

Comment: @einpoklum _"I want the specific term, that's all."_ Regarding c++ it's the `reinterpret_cast<>`, regarding c it's just the _cast_. That simple.

Comment: No, it is not. You can reinterpret_cast between non-void types, or from non void to void etc.

Comment: @einpoklum _"No, it is not. You can reinterpret_cast between non-void types"_ And what?? Why do you think `void*` should be a special case? Clarify your question please to get better answers regarding your unclear concerns.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: PreferenceBean understood it just fine. And "there is no well-known special term for that" is also an answer.

Comment: @einpoklum Well, then accept lightness answer, or improve your question with some essence of what you're really asking about.

Comment: Added a note. As for @PreferenceBean's answer, it's ok-ish, but I'm looking for something people use.

Comment: @einpoklum People use the term _cast_ or _reinterpret cast_ are you going to ask about opinions (which is off-topic)?

Comment: People _you know_ only use the general term.